# How to redirect to Index.cshtml on HTML pages? 

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a button that redirect to @Url.Action("Index", "Home") it is part of the main menu located in all pages included both HTML and cshtml. So I don't know how to tell to HTML ones to redirect to Index cshtml when the button is clicked.

*HTML pages are the 80% of the content in the website.

*Im currently using ASP.Net MVC 3

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want is to link the *static* HTML pages to the `Index` action of `HomeController`, a simple html link should do the trick:

```
<a href="/home/index">Home</a>
```

Comment: Should I use ~/home/index, the htmls pages are not in the same level of mvc views

Comment: `~/home/index` will not work for static html pages, the `~` is parsed by the ASP.NET (MVC) engine and converted to a full url, but no parsing takes place on a static html page. You'll have to see how the generated url looks like and set in manually in the `href` attribute of the link. What does the url generated by `@Url.Action("Index", "Home")` look like?

Answer (score 2):

Since this Q is already answered just some additional info going the other way - if you want to tell your cshtml files to redirect to your html files inside of an application besides direct linking (or using /../../SomeFolder) you can use

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Home/Index.html")">Home</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

Response.Redirect(page.GetRouteUrl("Default", new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" }), false);
```